Is "go back" correct in this sales copy?
In the opening sale, we set the price to $60. After the opening sale, the price will be $70. But $60 is actually the very first price. There is no other price to go back to. So I don't know if "go back" works?

Price goes back to $70/month after Friday 18th May


"will go back to" is not appropriate there. "will go to".  You can call $60 a "special introductory price".  Or, in sales talk, "For the low low introductory price of only $60."

@TimR, thanks for the comment. Is "will be" better than "will go to" since it's better to be concise in a sales copy?

Concision is important on internal memos but if these words are intended for the potential customer, you also have to grab the customer's attention in a way that makes them want to act.  So, for example, "will go up to $70" is more attention-getting and compelling than "will be $70".

@TimR, do I have to use "will"? Can I simply say "goes up to"?

Yes, you can use simple present "goes up to" with a future sense.
